# Google Sheets appendrow() function viewing dropdowns as cell content even though they are empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use the script function appendrow() to move rows to sheet that has drop-down and checkbox data validation (data validation is present on the source sheet too and mirrors the target sheet's data validation). The problem I'm having is that rows are being appended all the way down at row 1000 on the target sheet. When I remove the drop-downs, it appends the rows correctly. I need the data validation to be present though, in case changes need to be made to those cells. The data validation is applied to several columns (e.g. F2:F).

I need to know how to insert the row after the header because the dropdowns and checkboxes are apparently viewed as content according to the appendrow() function.

Current script:

```
function onEdit(e) {

var ss = e.source,
sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
    range = e.range,
    targetSheet,
    columnNumberToWatch = 14;
if (sheet.getName() === "Pending Bookings" && e.value === "CONFIRMED" && 
e.range.columnStart === columnNumberToWatch) {
    targetSheet = "Confirmed Bookings"
} else if (sheet.getName() === "Confirmed Bookings" && e.value === "" && 
e.range.columnStart === columnNumberToWatch) {
    targetSheet = "Pending Bookings"
}
ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet)
.appendRow(sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn())
.getValues()[0])
sheet.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
}
```

Comment: I have a data validation rule in column one and I can append lines in this way: `function appendRow() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow(['','Yes','Maybe','No Way', 'Come back tommorow and try again'])
}` and there is no problem at all as long as the validation is in it's default state (i.e. nothing selected).  If one is selected near the bottom then that next line is where appending begins.

Answer (score 1):

**Appending Rows with Validation Columns**

```
function AppendingARow() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var vA=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getMaxRow()-1,1).getValues();//save the validation
  sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getMaxRows()-1,1).clear();//clear the validation
  var vB=sh.getRange(2,3,sh.getMaxRows()-1,1).getValues();
  sh.getRange(2,3,sh.getMaxRows()-1,1).clear();
  sh.appendRow(['','Yes','','Maybe','No Way', 'Come back tommorow and try again']);//append the row
  sh.getRange(2,1,vA.length,1).setValues(vA);//restore the validation
  sh.getRange(2,3,vB.length,1).setValues(vB);
}
```

Here's what my spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

I put it into a function:

```
function AppendRow(cA,rowA,tsh) {
  var cObj={cA:[]};
  cObj.cA=cA;
  cObj.cA.forEach(function(c){
    cObj[c]=tsh.getRange(2,c,tsh.getMaxRows(),1).getValues();//save validations
    tsh.getRange(2,c,tsh.getMaxRows(),1).clear();//clear validation
  });
  cObj.lr=tsh.getLastRow();//get and save last row
  cObj.cA.forEach(function(c){
    tsh.getRange(2,c,cObj[c].length,1).setValues(cObj[c]);//return validations        
  });
  tsh.getRange(cObj.lr+1,1,1,rowA.length).setValues([rowA]);//Insert new row. This approach preserves the values in the inserted row
}
```

> cA is the array of columns of validation data
>
> rowA is the row that your trying to append.  It's a one dimensional array.
>
> tsh is the targetsheet

I tested this on my simple example but lets see what happens on yours.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper. Is there a way to integrate that method using the script that I have or will I have to completely rethink it? (added for reference)

Comment: Which columns have validation?

Comment: 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 14, 15

Comment: Does the targetsheet have any headers?

Comment: Note: my first function was using getMaxColumns() when it should have been getMaxRows()...I'm surprized it worked at all.

Comment: I changed my function a little because I realized this morning that I was preserving the validation columns of the inserted row.

Comment: It does have headers. I'll go ahead and give it a shot and let you know what happens. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by moving the data from one sheet to the other with a smarter `Range` selection.

With a sheet like this:

[image: source before running]
[image: destination before running]

You can use a script:

```
function appendWithValidation() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Source");
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Destination");

  var newData = source.getDataRange().getValues();

  while (destination.getDataRange().getValues().length>destination.getMaxRows()) {
    destination.deleteRow(destination.getMaxRows());
  }

  for (var i=0; i<newData.length; i++) {
    destination.appendRow(newData[i]);
  }

  source.getDataRange().clear();
}
```

That will create the following result:

[image: source after running]
[image: destination before running]